# Porting character buffers into Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

I am trying to run C code in R using Rcpp, but am unsure how to convert a buffer used to hold data from a file. In the third line of code below, I allocate an unsigned char buffer and my problem is that I don't know what Rcpp data type to use. Once the data are read into the buffer, I figured out how to use Rcpp::NumericMatrix to hold the final result, but not the character buffer. I have seen several responses by Dirk Eddelbuettel to similar questions where he suggests replacing all 'malloc' calls with Rcpp initialization commands. I tried using an Rcpp::CharacterVector, but then there is a type mismatch in the loop at the end: the Rcpp::CharacterVector cannot be read as an unsigned long long int. The code runs for some C-compilers, but throws a 'memory corruption' error for others, so I would prefer to do things the way Dirk suggests (use Rcpp data types) so that the code will run regardless of the specific compiler.

```
    FILE *fp = fopen( filename, "r" );
    fseek( fp, index_data_offset, SEEK_SET );
    unsigned char* buf = (unsigned char *)malloc( 3 * number_of_index_entries * sizeof(unsigned long long int) );
    fread( buf, sizeof("unsigned long long int"), (long)(3 * number_of_index_entries), fp );
    fclose( fp );

    // Convert "buf" into a 3-column matrix.
    unsigned long long int l;
    Rcpp::NumericMatrix ToC(3, number_of_index_entries);
    for (int col=0; col<number_of_index_entries; col++ ) {
        l = 0;
        int offset = (col*3 + 0)*sizeof(unsigned long long int);
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
            l = l | ((unsigned long long int)buf[i+offset] << (8 * i));
        }
        ToC(0,col) = l;

        l = 0;
        offset = (col*3 + 1)*sizeof(unsigned long long int);
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
            l = l | ((unsigned long long int)buf[i+offset] << (8 * i));
        }
        ToC(1,col) = l;

        l = 0;
        offset = (col*3 + 2)*sizeof(unsigned long long int);
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
            l = l | ((unsigned long long int)buf[i+offset] << (8 * i));
        }
        ToC(2,col) = l;
    }
    return( ToC );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C and C++ can be lovely. If you know what you're doing, you have both a *very* direct line to the underlying hardware *and* higher-level abstraction for efficient reasoning.

I would suggest to simplify and reduce the problem.  Start with a simple and known case, for example an STL vector of `double`. Let's call is `x`. Fill it with 10 or hundred elements, then open a `FILE` and write a blob from

```
x.data(),  x.size() * sizeof(double)
```

Close the file. The read it into Rcpp by first allocation a `NumericVector v` of the same size, then reading the bytes back and then calling `memcpy` to `&(v[0])`.

It should be the same vector.

Then you can generalize to different types.  *Because vectors are guaranteed to be contiguous memory* you can this serialization trick directly.

You can do variations on this with character buffers, or `void*`, or ... None of that matters *for as long as you are careful not to mismatch*. *I.e.* don't assing an `int` payload to a `double` and so on.

Now, is any this *recommended*?  Hell no, unless you are chasing performance and know well enough what you are doing in which case it is reasonable. Otherwise rely on *fantastic* existing packages like [fst](http://cloud.r-project.org/package=fst) or [qs](http://cloud.r-project.org/package=qs)
 to do it for you.

I hope this helps with your question. I wasn't entirely *what* it was you were asking.  Maybe you clarify (and possibly shorten / focus) it if not.

Answer (score 0):

A typecast did the trick:

```
    Rcpp::NumericVector NumVecBuf( 3 * number_of_index_entries * sizeof(unsigned long long int) );
    unsigned char* buf = (unsigned char*) &(NumVecBuf[0]);
```

Dirk's statement about "contiguous memory" suggested that this would work, so I went ahead and marked his comment as the answer. Thanks, Dirk! And, thanks for developing and maintaining Rcpp!

Comment: Your answer/quesiton isn't necessarily wrong, but since Rcpp is C++, I'd suggest using C++ constructs for consistency.  E.g. `std::ifstream` instead of `FILE` handle, `reinterpret_cast` instead of C-style cast, etc.  You should also probably use `sizeof(double)` since NumericMatrix represents floating point data.

Comment: You might also have a look at `Rcpp::RawVector` which is meant for storing raw binary data.

Comment: Or even `XPtr` if you just want access "other" objects.